# Reference chart within placeholder (Powerpoint)

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint, placeholder

I am using the code at the bottom of the following link http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=147605 to update the source file all of my charts within PowerPoint.

The problem is, is that all of my charts reside within placeholders and I don't know how to reference them. i.e. The sh.Type in the code below is always 14 - msoPlaceholder.

```
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
sld.Select
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        MsgBox sh.Name
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            With sh.LinkFormat
```

Can any one tell me how to reference the chart within the placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works...

```
If sh.Type = msoPlaceholder And sh.HasChart = msoTrue
```